# Allow user to enter only alphabets and number ERROR

Tags: jquery, html

Am using following code to block these letters `#$%^&*()`

**My problem is when i copy and paste these letters in input field** these letters get pasted how do i block even when user tries to paste

```
$('#textinput').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9@]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textinput" name="mname" type="text" placeholder="Sanoj Lawrence" class="form-control input-md">preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Please fix the tags and precisewhat error you get.

Comment: @Dici what tag and where to

Comment: guys please explain whats wrong

Comment: nobody knows what's wrong as you didn't tell us what error you were getting.

Comment: I have fixed your tags. Now, what is the exact error that you are seeing? Although we are happy to help you we don't have time to recreate your issue to find out what the error is. Always post the exact error you are getting if you want a better answer faster.

Comment: Probably want `document.myForm.price.value` (note `price` not `name`)

Comment: Why would you want only "alphabets" in a price text box?

Comment: You do not have a `return true;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want it so a user cant enter numbers a simple way of doing it is like this.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="validate(event)"/>

<script>
function validate(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode( key );
    var regex = /[0-9]/;
    if( regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}    
</script>
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/d0mog5vd/1/) demo of it working

**EDIT** changed it to only be the characters specified in comments

```
function validate(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode( key );
    var regex = /[a-z A-Z @ .]/;
    if(!regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/d0mog5vd/2/) with the modifed regex

Comment: how do i make a text box for email by adding the filter letter inside  var regex = /[/*letters i need to filter*/]/;   will it work

Comment: you can use `<input type="email"/>` which will check if it is a valid character combination for an email address?

Comment: but its not validating

Comment: in a text box i need to allow only alphabets, number,and @ , and . (dot) these are accepted charter in input box how do i do this

Comment: the above code will allow them just not numbers, and it doesn't check when the form is submitted it just doesn't allow them when a user is typing in the textbox

Comment: yea that's right  i need to allow only these charter alphabets, number,and @ , and . (dot)  i need to block symbol like this #$%%^&*()

Comment: i need to BLOCK  all symbol except @ and . (dot)

Comment: It will now only allow letters, @ and .   hope that helps, and if it is what you were after please accept my answer

Comment: When i copy and paste the filter element are pasted

Comment: add this inside your input `onpaste="return false"` it will stop the ability to paste into the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a `return:true;`

```
if( validate() ){ // This will never be true, only false or null
    console.log("Valid!");
}
```